# change or add data to Sidekiq Web UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, worker, sidekiq-monitor

I'm using sidekiq Pro and usually monitor my workers' process on their Web UI. Whenever there's an Error, the task is moved to Retries tab where the queue name and an error messsage are displayed. The thing is I would like to add data to this message (specifically class name and line number), but i havent found information about this anywhere. Is it possible to edit/configure the Web UI display? If that's so, how?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to edit/configure the Web UI display? If that's so,
>   how?

Yes, it is possible. One way to achieve additional monitoring information is building a custom UI page. You gonna need to define a module containing request handling logics and register that module as a Sidekiq web page:

```
module WebAddition
  def self.registered(app)
    app.get('/desired_path') do
      # you can define @instance_variables for passing into template
      # Sidekiq uses erb for its templates so you should do it aswell
      erb File.read(path_to_desired_erb_file)
    end 
  end
end

# here we instruct Sidekiq to take our UI extension onboard
Sidekiq::Web.register WebAddition
# in case you want to provide localization, it's achieved here
Sidekiq::Web.locales << File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/web/locales")
# the name of your tab (at the left hand) gonna be translated
# using the provided locale file (if any).
# right hand of the equation should be equal to the path you specified
# in registered() method
Sidekiq::Web.tabs['disappeared_jobs'] = 'desired_path'
```

Another option (although strongly not recommended) could be to monkeypatch Sidekiq UI code itself. Take a look at [Sidekiq WebApplication](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/web/application.rb) class, change the methods you're intrested in and update according *.erb files located in [web/views](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/web/views) folder.